# Removing the roslaunch cache

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first time running `roslaunch` after a rebuild or after a reboot, etc, there is a noticeable delay while paths to executables are cached, etc, or at least that is what I presume happens.

On my system with about 120 packages, I have a startup timing bug that most often manifests itself when there is a slow `roslaunch`. Is there a file or directory to delete or a `roslaunch` parameter, etc that I can use to force `roslaunch` to start from a clean setting?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292088/removing-the-roslaunch-cache/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/211848/what-makes-rosbag-to-start-playing-fast/?answer=211852#post-id-211852) is what my real issue is. Using the suggested `vmtouch` tool I can reproduce my problem.

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1